# Contraseñas encriptadas no no coinciden!

Tags: php

Que tal estoy haciendo un login en el cual quiero ingresar comparando contraseñas encriptadas pero  recibo la contraseña del input del formulario y la encripto con password_hash y me da una diferente a la que esta registrada en la base de datos y al momento de compararlas no coinciden y me no puedo accesar. estas son las contraseñas que me muestra contraseña encriptada recibida del formulario $2y$10$HdGWEyBw1GLsQyBsZBV.BupPkeapiRoXopo.Be9MMKyWGxU30/LpO
contraseña registrada en la base de datos $2y$10$xFsB/YL5fPcCtj9T.YvA8OwyKhW15qUT.Jq/l7BwZoxQGbl7WVOWq.

```
function iniciarSesion() {

if(isset($_POST["btn_IniSesion"])) {
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];

    $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];

    $contrasena = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`introducir el código aquí`

    $conexionBD = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sistemaventarenta");
    echo "<br>";
    //se verifica si hay conexion
    if (!$conexionBD->set_charset("utf8")) {
       printf("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8: %s\n", $conexionBD->error);
       exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $queryIniUsuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '".$correo."'";
        try
        {
            $resulConsulta = mysqli_query($conexionBD, $queryIniUsuario);

            $resulUsuario = mysqli_num_rows($resulConsulta);
            if($resulUsuario > 0)
            {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulConsulta); 

                $password = $row['contrasena'];

                if ($correo == "") {
                    echo '<p class="fallo" style="text-align: center;>El correo electrónico no es 
 correcto.<p>';
                    }
                    else if (password_verify($password,$contrasena))
                        $_SESSION["correo"] = $row["correo"];
                        header('Location: index.php');//lo redirecciona al index
                    }
                else
                {
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo '<p class="fallo" style="text-align: center;">La contraseña no es correcta.<p>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<br>";
                echo '<p class="fallo" style="text-align: center;">El usuario(Correo Electrónico) es incorrecto.<p>';
            }
        }
        catch(Excepcion $e)
        {
            echo '<p class ="fallo">Hubo un error al conectarse a la base de datos<p>';
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

el asunto esta en la funcion `password_verify`. Esta funcion evalua una cadena DESENCRIPTADA, con un HASH.

en tu codigo estas convirtiendo el parametro $_POST['contrasena'] con un hash:

```
$contrasena = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

luego cojes el password de la bbdd (despues de tus evaluaciones) :

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulConsulta); 
$password = $row['contrasena'];
```

cuando comparas la contraseña en:

```
password_verify($password,$contrasena)
```

realmente estas comparando un $password de bbdd (que sera un hash) con una $contrasena que has puesto como hash. El metodo intenta "convertir" el $password en un hash para compararlo con $contraseña, con lo que esta haciendo 2 veces una conversion, y no van a coincidir.

lo que deberias comprobar en password_verify es:

```
password_verify($_POST['contrasena'], $password)
```

Si lo quieres de otra manera, comenta la linea:

```
$contrasena = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

fuente: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php

Comment: muchas gracias de antemano, ya funciona, ya anteriormente lo había hecho así, pero me salia este mensaje "tu contraseña quedo expuesta a una violación de la seguridad de los datos que se introdujo en un sitio web o una app." y pensé que era falta de seguridad e investigue y lo que entendí es que estaba haciendo pruebas con una contraseña que contiene solo números registre otro usuario con una contraseña diferente y ya no me aparece.